# What is the <> operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just ran into JavaScript code which looks like this:

```js
let b = 0;
let d = 1 <b> 2;
console.log(d)
```

So what does `<b>` mean?

Comment: add parentheses `(1 < b) > 2`

Comment: where have you found this code?

Comment: It will always evaluate to `false`.  No boolean expression can be greater than 2.

Comment: @NinaScholz friend of mine was having some question and I saw this in this code

Comment: At first glance, I thought it was some misplaced `<b></b>` tag.

Comment: `<>` is not the same thing as `<b>`.

Comment: Probably some typescript type assertion they tried to do here but it seems wrong anyway.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: Ask your friend what `=> x <=` does, like in  `( b => b <= b )(8)` :)

Comment: @axiac It's not the same thing, but it is reasonable to think that `<>` is the operator in that expression, with `1`, `b`, and `2` as operands. It wouldn't be the only [operator that syntactically surrounds an operand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) nor even the only [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which does that.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is no `<>` operator in JavaScript. `let d = 1 <b> 2;` is the same as:

```
let d = (1 < b) > 2;
```

Which is always false, because `1 < b` is either `true` or `false` and `true > 2` and `false > 2` are both false.